# magento 2.3.5 image cache being auto generated

Tags: product-images, cache, image, image-resize

Images inside cache folder are being auto generated

I've truncate 3 specific folder that I know we don't need it after while checking again it has generated all over again when there hasn't been image resize called.

E.G:

```
root@jv-webdb-01 cache]# ls -la bb6cd3821999ba83509fb2097677c3f7
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 jv.com jv.com 4096 Jul  8 16:47 .
drwxrwxr-x 68 jv.com jv.com 4096 Jul  8 18:08 ..
[root@jv-webdb-01 cache]# ls -la bb6cd3821999ba83509fb2097677c3f7
total 40
drwxrwxr-x 10 jv.com jv.com 4096 Jul  8 18:19 .
drwxrwxr-x 68 jv.com jv.com 4096 Jul  8 18:08 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 jv.com jv.com 4096 Jul  8 18:19 b
drwxrwxr-x  3 jv.com jv.com 4096 Jul  8 18:19 B
drwxrwxr-x  3 jv.com jv.com 4096 Jul  8 18:15 h
drwxrwxr-x  3 jv.com jv.com 4096 Jul  8 18:17 l
drwxrwxr-x  3 jv.com jv.com 4096 Jul  8 18:14 m
drwxrwxr-x  3 jv.com jv.com 4096 Jul  8 18:14 v
drwxrwxr-x  4 jv.com jv.com 4096 Jul  8 18:14 w
drwxrwxr-x  3 jv.com jv.com 4096 Jul  8 18:14 W
[root@jv-webdb-01 cache]#
```

Anyone any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that images in /cache/folder is auto generated on demand if they aren't cached and get request the re-generated from the original if exists and according to the sizes for specific settings, but it can be confusing as to which cache folder is for which sizes, E.G: small, thumbnail, base etc...

Where could I find this dynamic created folder, is in DB table ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you run storefront at that time cache folder's images auto generated.
It's magento's behavior for page speed purpose.

what's you are looking for exactly??